# For a responsive calculator layout like windows 10, Grid can be used for both width and height?

Tags: html, css

I have to implement a calculator layout like windows 10 and make it responsive (both width and height). For width, I used percentage. For height, firstly I used px, it didn't work! then I tried to use Grid, but it didn't work either! finally, I used percentage.
I want to know if Grid can be used for height?

[Normal view, when height is smaller than a certain value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBcch.jpg)

[When height is smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCD3y.jpg)

```css
body, html{
       background-color: #e6e6e6;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       min-width:150px;
       min-height: 280px;
       cursor: default;
   }

.maincontainer {
 display: flex;
 height: 100%;
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.column1 {
 width: 65%;
 height: 100%;
}

.column2 {
 width: 35%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little vague. A reference image showing what you're trying to achieve will help keep everyone of the same page.

Please also include any HTML markup you're using and some snippets of CSS code you've tried.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow, Kindly share your code so that we can help you specifically to resolve the problem.

Comment: Dear @Craig , I've added 2 images an snippets of CSS to make clear what I meant, Could you please check my question again?

Comment: Dear @MDMNauman I edited my question, could u please review that?